# "Edit WCF Configuration..." menu item doesn't exist

Tags: wcf

In a console application, I've added an application configuration file named `App.config`. For safety, in the configuration file, I've also added a section `<system.serviceModel />`. As I know there must be by default a menu entity called `"Edit WCF Configuration ..."` as soon as I right click on `App.config`. But there isn't that entity. Also, restarting and starting VS with administrator permission as no effect. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved my problem by simply go to `Tools` in the menu bar, then click on `WCF Service Configuration Service Editor`. Once the tool has launched, every time I right click on the App.config, the menu entity `"Edit WCF Configuration"` appears.

Comment: yep this is the odd behavior of this tool - every time you start VS you need to run the tool before it appears on the context menu of the config file. I assume this is by design but is very strange behavior IMO